# different in Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT SUM(
  CASE WHEN RESTORE_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(MI,SHUTDOWN_TIMESTAMP,RESTORE_TIMESTAMP)
  ELSE DATEDIFF(MI,SHUTDOWN_TIMESTAMP,GETDATE()) END )
   AS downtime
  FROM TX_QUAD_STATUS NOLOCK
```

and i am getting this error.

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Comment: psst - `COALESCE(RESTORE_TIMESTAMP,GETDATE())` will return `RESTORE_TIMESTAMP` if its not `NULL`, otherwise it will return `GETDATE()`s return value.

Comment: Check your return type and it's size and variable in which you are returning the value

Answer (score 4):

[`SUM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) converts its result into an appropriate datatype, based on the input values. So you might be able to solve this by running the sum against a larger type:

```sql
SELECT SUM(
          CONVERT(
             bigint,
             DATEDIFF(minute,SHUTDOWN_TIMESTAMP,COALESCE(RESTORE_TIMESTAMP,GETDATE()))
          )
       )AS downtime
FROM TX_QUAD_STATUS NOLOCK
```

If `bigint` doesn't work, you might try `decimal(38,0)`.

(As mentioned in my comment to your Q, I've also replaced the whole `CASE` expression with a [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, then, the sum over those rows is huge. You could try casting as `bigint`, but I suspect you'll get enough idea if you drop the sum, and just look at the individual values:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN RESTORE_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(MI,SHUTDOWN_TIMESTAMP,RESTORE_TIMESTAMP)
  ELSE DATEDIFF(MI,SHUTDOWN_TIMESTAMP,GETDATE()) END
   AS downtime
  FROM TX_QUAD_STATUS NOLOCK
```

which will give you an idea of the numbers involved. Now add them up - if they are over 2 billion: problems.

Answer (score 1):

The result obtained is bigger that the value that can hold an INT variable.